# terminal-emulator settings controlling the rendering of bold typeface

Tags: colors, terminal-emulator, terminfo, ansi

The effect of bold typeface (ANSI: `CSI 1 m`) seems to depend on the terminal emulator.  For example, running the following script on different terminal emulators

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "TERM = $TERM"
for mode in 0 2 1 '1;2'; do
    printf '\033[%s;38;5;%dm\033[48;5;%dm%s\033[0m\n' "$mode" 0 15 "testing ($mode)"
done
```

gives the following output

[image]

Of the terminal emulators tested, only `xterm` properly renders bold text (mode=1).  The other terminal emulators seem to select a brighter color for bold typeface (generally also combining this with a bold typeface).  Oddly, `st` produces properly colored, bold text when given the parameters `1;2`, corresponding to `bold;faint`.

Thinking that perhaps these terminal emulators expect different control sequences for bold typeface, I checked `terminfo`, but found unanimity

```
$ for term in xterm-256color st-256color rxvt-unicode-256color tmux-256color; do printf "%-24s" "$term"; TERM=$term tput bold | cat -v; echo; done
xterm-256color          ^[[1m
st-256color             ^[[1m
rxvt-unicode-256color   ^[[1m
tmux-256color           ^[[1m
```

This leads to the question, what terminal-emulator parameters control the effect of bold typeface?  How can the shift to brighter color be prevented?  Can this be fixed through `Xresources` or `terminfo` customization?  (As an aside, are there corresponding parameters for `vim`?  It shows similar behavior, which does not necessarily correspond to that of the terminal emulator in which it is run.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one escape sequence that results in bold typeface, the `CSI 1 m` as you've noted.

Because of this, there is not *really* a way you could change the behavior from the application's (e.g. `vim`'s) side, not even through configuration such as the terminfo definitions. (I'll refine this statement in a second.)

The way to achieve the desired behavior is to configure the terminal emulator accordingly. You're looking for `xterm +pc` or `urxvt +is`, or their corresponding Xresource setting as shown in their manual. I don't know if `st` has such an option.

I really don't think `tmux` has such an option, since it cannot control how the graphical emulator will actually behave. Theoretically it might try the trick I'll mention in a second, but I really don't think it does.

---

To give a bit of historical context:

According to the standards, `CSI 1 m` means "bold or increased intensity", so strictly speaking, both behaviors are correct. Historically, graphical terminal emulators enabled both.

This kinda made sense with the traditional 8/16 color palette. Not so much with the extended 256-color palette that later became widespread, and not at all with RGB, supported by most graphical terminal emulators nowadays. And it's really bad there's no escape sequence that reliably produces the first 8 palette colors (practically the user's most preferred 8 colors) in bold typeface.

Seeing this, recently several terminal emulators made a shift towards not brightening the color, only making the font bolder (what you're looking for). I don't think any of the terminals you mentioned made this change of the default yet, but my knowledge might easily be out of date on them.

---

I mentioned that there *might* be a way to change the behavior from the app.

There are two escape sequences to request one of the first 8 palette colors: the legacy one (`CSI 30..37 m`) and the 256-color one with such an index (`CSI 38;5;0..7 m`). Certain versions of certain terminal emulators might behave differently for the two, if combined with the bold/bright attribute `CSI 1 m`. For example, if I recall correctly, some versions of `xterm` changed to brighter color only if the legacy color escapes were used, but not if the 256-color ones. If I recall correctly, xterm later changed this behavior.

Anyway, if you happen to use such a terminal emulator, a workaround could be to modify `setaf` in your terminfo to emit the 256-color sequences for the first 8 colors, rather than the legacy codes.

This won't change the behavior of the bold/bright `CSI 1 m` over the default foreground color, and I definitely recommend going with configuring the terminal emulator instead of using this terminfo hack.

---

If you're interested in further juicy/hairy details, you might be interested in these links, as well as other pages linked from there:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=762247
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=791596

Comment: Thank you very much, those are precisely the flags I was looking for.  I can also confirm that the terminal behavior carries over to `vim` (both when run alone in the terminal and within a `tmux` session).  I will look into whether something similar can be done for `st`.  It appears that the `boldColors` resource of `xterm` (a boolean, set by `-pc` / `+pc`) takes effect in print.c (`fg -=8`), so that will provide a basis for examination of `st`'s source.

Answer (score -1):

As [egmont](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/53656/egmont) [pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/691132), the bold-as-bright behavior can be suppressed in `xterm` and `urxvt` by running `xterm +pc` or `urxvt +is`.  For those wondering about [`st`](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/LICENSE.html), its bold-as-bright behavior is implemented in `xdrawglyphfontspecs()` in [x.c](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/x.c.html),

```
/* Change basic system colors [0-7] to bright system colors [8-15] */
if ((base.mode & ATTR_BOLD_FAINT) == ATTR_BOLD && BETWEEN(base.fg, 0, 7))
    fg = &dc.col[base.fg + 8];
```

where `BETWEEN()` is, as its name suggests,

```
#define BETWEEN(x, a, b)    ((a) <= (x) && (x) <= (b))
```

The substitution only applies to the first 8 colors of the traditional 8/16 color palette, which aligns with egmont's remarks. The header [st.h](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/st.h.html) defines `ATTR_BOLD_FAINT` as the bitwise-or of `ATTR_BOLD = 1<<0` and `ATTR_FAINT = 1<<1`.  The color remapping therefore only occurs when the bold attribute is set but the faint attribute is not also set.  Whether intentional or not, passing escape sequences for both bold (`CSI 1 m`) and faint (`CSI 2 m`) attributes produces bold font, as shown in the question, by not satisfying this conditional.

In principle, one could take advantage of the bold-but-not-faint conditional to obtain bold text, by either changing the escape sequence for the bold attribute in [st.info](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/st.info.html) from its canonical value (`\E[1m`) to `\E[1;2m`, or alternatively by setting the faint attribute whenever the bold attribute is set (by modifying `case 1` of `tsetattr()` in [st.c](https://git.suckless.org/st/file/st.c.html) to `term.c.attr.mode |= (ATTR_BOLD | ATTR_FAINT)`).  Although either of these changes produces the desired results (tested with the script in the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/690694)), neither one is recommended (for a variety of reasons).

A more straightforward (and preferred) approach is to simply remove the bold-as-bright conditional in `xdrawglyphfontspecs()`, and, as it turns out, there is already a [patch](https://st.suckless.org/patches/bold-is-not-bright/) that does exactly that.